# Open Link to Album in iTunes Store

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm adding a "Buy on iTunes" button and need to know how to open the iTunes url in the iTunes Store.  Can I just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/trash-talk-ep/id618452285#"]];`?

Comment: did you try it? What happened?

Comment: On the simulator it opens in Safari, but I'm not sure if it will open in the iTunes Store since I can't install on a device just yet.

Comment: It opened in Safari once but now it tells me the url is invalid.

Comment: you should add these details to the question. It will help people to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link works fine (I'm on a iPhone now). iTunes Store links don't work properly on the simulator, thus the error you're receiving. Since the simulator doesn't have an iTunes app, it can't open iTunes links.

Answer (score 0):

You're running it on the simulator and the simulator doesn't have the iTunes/App Store so it can't open it. Try it on a device, then it should work without any problems.